# Google Play Pre-registration: What Will Happen exactly after the 90 days limit

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Google says that "Pre-registration campaigns can only last 90 days"

[screenshot from Google Play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRYa3.png)

did anyone tried to let it more than 90 days? what happened to app page on Google Play?

Also, did the pre-registered users get a notification when you launch the app to production after the 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-registration) state that your app will be searchable on the play store, where users can pre-register for your app.

I've let one of my apps pass the 90 day point and it remains in "pre registration" within the console however, was removed from the Google play store until I push into the production track.

Others that i've pushed into production have resulted in users getting a push notification.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: hi, will the users who already pre registered will get push notification ?